# Как скачать и прочитать файл с сервера в xamarin.forms, чтобы пользователь не имел к нему доступ?

Tags: c#, файлы, xamarin, httpclient, xamarin.forms

У меня есть приложение xamarin forms, которое связано с api. По запросу из приложения API возвращает текст geojson файла. Мне нужно сохранить и прочитать этот файл в моем приложении, но так, чтобы пользователь не мог удалить этот файл не удаляя приложение и не имел доступ к файлу. Как это сделать?

Comment: А что именно не получается? Скачать, десереализовать, или записать? Или все аместе?

Comment: Для того чтобы пользователь не мог иметь доступ к этому файлу его надо сохранить в папке с программой на устройстве(НЕ SD card) в Java этот метод `getFilesDir()` дает путь к папке с программой (но если у пользоватетля есть root права к этой папке он также будет иметь доступ)